# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working in online sql editors

Tags: sql, on-duplicate-key

I'm learning SQL by using online code editors that can run the code, e.g. techonthenet.com or w3schools. The problem is, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command doesn't seem to work in those editors. Here's a link to one example https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_try_sql.php . I'm trying to update the customers database. If I use just INSERT command it seems to work fine, but when I try ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Parse error on line 2:
..., 'new first name')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPD
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', 'COMMA', 'RPAR', 'END', 'WHEN', 'ELSE', 'OUTPUT', 'GO', 'SEMICOLON', got 'ON'
```

My code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, last_name, first_name)
VALUES ('4000', 'new last name', 'new first name')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_name = 'new last name', first_name = 'new first name';
```

Am I doing sth wrong or are those websites not fully functioning?

Comment: This is a MySQL/MariaDB specific extension of the `INSERT` statement - not an ANSI/ISO SQL Standard feature. It's typically **NOT** supported by any other RDBMS engines, so depending on what engine those online sites are modelled after, this will obviously not work....

Comment: Oh, thanks for explanation. Is there a way to achieve a similar result (that is inserting a new value or replacing an old one) in Standard SQL without any extensions?

Answer (score 0):

A [MERGE INTO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) is standard Sql.
But it seems that upserts are not supported by [techonthenet](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/try_sql_features.php)

```
MERGE INTO customers tgt
USING (
  SELECT 
    4000 AS customer_id,
    'new last name' AS last_name, 
    'new first name' AS first_name
) src ON (src.customer_id = tgt.customer_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET last_name = src.last_name
             , first_name = src.first_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (customer_id, last_name, first_name) 
    VALUES (src.customer_id, src.last_name, src.first_name)
```